# WPF: combox values used as filter but data from last selection will be shown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm using wpf for a small app in which I have 3 comboboxes (year, month, category). In this 3 comboboxes you can select values and afterwars the datagrid below shows the data from the selected values above. My problem is that I select one, but nothing happens. If I select the next one the data from before will be shown. For example I change year from *all* to *2019*, then the data from *all* will be shown. If I now change to *2018* the data from *2019* will be shown. Any ideas why?

code snippet:

```
private void cmbYear_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        fillMonthBox();
        updateData();
    }

    private void CmbMonth_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateData();
    }
    private void CmbCategory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateData();
    }

    private void updateData() {
        getCmbValues();
        initalizeDatagrid();
    }

    private void initalizeDatagrid() {
        List<Budget> budget = new List<Budget>();
        budget.Add(new Budget() { Datum = "gesamt", Einnahmen = calculate(true), Ausgaben = calculate(false) }) ;
        dgBudget.ItemsSource = budget;
    }

    private double calculate(bool isIncome)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        List<Entry> entriesList = entries.entries;
        if (isIncome) {
            entriesList = entriesList.Where(x => x.value > 0).ToList();
        }
        else {
            entriesList = entriesList.Where(x => x.value < 0).ToList();
        }
        if (year != null) {
            entriesList = entriesList.Where(x => x.dateTime.Year == Int32.Parse(year)).ToList();
        } 
        if (month != null) {
            entriesList = entriesList.Where(x => x.dateTime.Month == DateTime.ParseExact(month, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month).ToList();
        }
        if (category != null) {
            entriesList = entriesList.Where(x => x.category.name == category).ToList();
        }
        entriesList.ForEach(x => sum += x.value);
        return Math.Abs(sum);
    }

    private void getCmbValues() {
        year = cmbYear.Text;
        month = cmbMonth.Text;
        category = cmbCategory.Text;

        if (year == all) {
            year = null;
        }
        if (month == all) {
            month = null;
        }
        if (category == all) {
            category = null;
        }
    }
}

public class Budget
{
    public string Datum { get; set; }

    public double Einnahmen { get; set; }

    public double Ausgaben { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the place you are reading the combo box values.
Please use the following code for the same

> year = (cmbYear.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content;

Comment: Because, year = cmbYear.Text; will return the last selected item only

Comment: you can also use [year = (cmbYear.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content;] as well.